# Jquery file upload: single file upload for drag and drop

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery file upload extension (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) to make upload system on my website.

Problem is, I don't want allow users to upload multiple files through drag-and-drop zone, is there any way to restrict that and allow only single file upload? I've found only such restriction for button, and there is no info in wiki about single drag-and-drop upload.

Comment: just check the number of files being dropped and give an alert saying only single file allowed. because we can't stop user from dragging multiple files he should notified instead

Answer (score 0):

Looking at their documentation, the answer is there:

> Note that users can still drag&drop multiple files. To enforce a one
>   file upload limit, you can make use of the maxNumberOfFiles option
>   (see
>   [Options](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options)).

Comment: I've already tried that. It's limitation to overall file upload count, and will not affect drag-and-drop zone.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jquery.fileupload.validate.js to your site. Then the maxNumberOfFiles property will be taken into account.

You can set this to 1.

```
$('.something').fileupload({
    dropZone          : $('.your-dropzone'),
    url               : 'http://...',
    dataType          : 'json',
    maxNumberOfFiles  : 1
});
```

Comment: what if he drags multiple files and drops it ..which one would be taken into account ?

Comment: maxNumberOfFiles will affect on overall file upload count, not only the drag-and-drop.

Comment: @susheel: in this case validate would throw an error which you can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Resurrecting this q because I found a workaround for this, which I've needed to do myself...

The maxNumberOfFiles value, as DazVolt points out, applies to all the files uploaded in a session, not just a particular upload, because of this function in jquery.fileupload-ui.js, which basically counts the number of processed (i.e. already uploaded) table rows in the UI, which is then compared against maxNumberOfFiles later on:

```
getNumberOfFiles: function () {
                return this.filesContainer.children()
                    .not('.processing').length;
            },
```

Happily though, this definition of getNumberOfFiles can be changed...

To make it work per upload, i.e. restrict it to one file per upload but have as many uploads as you like I did this:

1. In the download template I added a class 'previouslyUploaded' to the template for the table row:

   `{% for (var i=0, file; file=o.files[i]; i++) { %}
        <tr class="template-download fade previouslyUploaded">`
2. Before I define the fileupload object, I make a new function to be called by getNumberOfFiles which counts the table rows but disregards those already uploaded i.e. those represented by entries in the download template:

   ```
   var perUploadRestriction = function () {
       // previouslyUploaded is a class added in template-download
       // with this query here it means previously uploaded files don't count towards the max_file_upload limit
       // only the files in the current upload in preparation
       return this.filesContainer.children().not('.processing').not('.previouslyUploaded').length;
   };
   ```
3. And then I use this function in the fileupload object definition as so:

   ```
       $(this).fileupload({
           dropZone: $(this),
           processQueue: [{
               action: 'validate', 
               //acceptFileTypes: *a regex object for your file types*, 
               maxFileSize: 5000000, 
               maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
           }],
           getNumberOfFiles: perUploadRestriction,
       });
   ```

And now, if I drag'n'drop more than one file to the dropzone I get an error message, but after a successful upload I can still make more uploads with the same restriction.

It's a bit of a hack, but works for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this issue. (Couldn't find a proper solution anywhere on the internet).

We assume we have this markup:

```
<input type="file" id="localfile" name="localfile" />

<label for="localfile" class="dropBox">Drop file here</label>
```

... and then javascript:

```
var droppedFiles = [];

$(function() {
 $('.dropBox').on('drop', function(e) {
   filesToDrop = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files
   droppedFiles.push(filesToDrop)

        if (droppedFiles.length > 1) {
                        
            alert("Please select only one file!")
            return false
        }
   })
})
```

So we basically every time we drop a file, we push that file to the `droppedFiles` array and then check if that array has more than 1 item, we `return false` and  alert the user with a message.